# OpenCV: ImportError: libavcodec.so.54

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I am using Ubuntu, and whenever I try to import cv2 to python I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libavcodec.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked online before posting and was unable to find a solution. I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove python-opencv; sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

but nothing worked.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look online and see which package holds libavcodec.so.54 and install that package. Possibly libavcodec-dev